# Why was this "Very Low Quality" flag declined, when the answer seemingly doesn't address the question?

Tags: support, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62859789/4108803) ([screenshot in case it gets deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgYuT.png)) as VLQ and the flag was declined with *"a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"*.

[In review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26655649), it was also marked as "Recommend deletion" twice.

In my view, this answer is not attempting to address the OP's issue in a very meaningful way ("it works for me" is a variant of "it works on my machine!"); are you going to let your coworkers skate with that? But that's beside the point.

I can elaborate further:

- it isn't stating why it works in a way that can help other people understand what's going on
- doesn't provide what steps led to that conclusion
- doesn't directly address the question, which is specifically about Chrome
- doesn't state what programming language it's written in (I guess it's PHP?), when the question doesn't have language tags

Though my reasoning must be flawed. Can you please help me understand why this answer is acceptable?

Comment: as you clearly explained, this *answer* doens't answer the question but it's not a *very low quality* one. You have to downvote it. It's still an attempt to answer (a very bad one)

Comment: @TemaniAfif *This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.* 
The answer I flagged seems to fit the description. It has severe content problems, and unlikely to be salvageable through editing. So I don't see why it's not a *very low quality* one. I probably don't understand what *quality* means in this case.

Comment: @blackgreen the VLQ flag is very subjective, often its helpful to just pretend it doesn't exist

Comment: *This answer has severe formatting or content problems* --> this is the problem here, we don't have a lot of content to talk about *severe* or problem**s**. The answer can also be *you can use utf8_encode($str)*. I agree that it's a very bad answer and need to deleted but to be considered as VLQ is subjective as @Nick pointed.

Comment: In the future, I recommend never using the "Very low quality" flag at all. For answers, "Not an answer" does exactly the same thing and it's more clear when it should be used, and for questions, "Very low quality" sends it to the Triage review queue so that other users can flag it as "Should be closed", so then it's better if you just flag it as "Should be closed" yourself.

Comment: For this specific answer, I don't think it should be deleted since it does answer the question, even though it's very short. In some specific cases it might even be useful, even though there is probably almost always a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: @DonaldDuck In my experience, from how my flags are handled, review audits, meta posts, etc, VLQ flags seem appropriate to address link-only answers. For other use cases, it seems a tricky one. I'll follow your advice.

Comment: @blackgreen I prefer to use Not An Answer for link-only answers as well because even though technically one can argue that they're answers, [this site doesn't consider them as answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/349538), and in any case they should be deleted just like posts that aren't answers. I never use the VLQ flag at all because I find it too confusing: sometimes it's not even available, and when it is it's often not clear when to use it, and when it is the VLQ flag does nothing that other flags don't do.

Comment: Please don't use the VLQ flag for an answer that can be edited to make sense. It needs to be used for gibberish only.

Comment: @BhargavRao is it okay to use the VLQ flag for link-only answers?

Comment: @blackgreen, yes you can use VLQ for link only and for non english posts.